# Storing areas and centers for polygons with postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table containing polygons that I will want to search by areas and centers. There are postgresql methods that calculate the area and centers of polygons, but as I intend to search on them, should I be writing the data to the table to prevent calculation and speed up searches, or would the data be redundant?

Comment: It wouldn't be redundant, it might however be harder to maintain and not needed. If you want to search by it you can start with indexes on those functions.

Comment: Ah, didn't know you could add indexes of function output. Would that pre-calculate and store the data internally?

Comment: Yes, it will. In the index.

Comment: In the index and for the index only. Index only scan is not supported for expressions (yet). So it will search for correct row but once it finds it it will run the function and check again. So if you have, say 100 rows and want to order by a function and select 10 the function will be run 10 times with the index instead of 100 without it.

Comment: @JakubKania will it run the function again even I don't select the function output?

Comment: Hmm...Not sure about that one. But that wouldn't be too hard to test.